# mySql foreign key name issue

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, primary-key, mysql-workbench

Hi I have designed a database in mysql workbench. When I went to forward engineer I got (errno: 121) because I had foreign keys named the same in multiple tables which I realized is not allowed. I have quite a few junction tables as mostly n:m relationships. I am using composite primary keys (made up of 2 foreign keys) for most of these junction tables. My question is do I have to rename these primary keys to be unique along with the foreign keys?
Appreciate some help please.

(I have not renamed the foreign keys yet in below code)

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`tblStudent` (
  `StudentID` INT(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `Student_Firstname` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
  `Student_Lastname` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
  `DOB` DATE NOT NULL ,
  `Student_Gender` ENUM('Male','Female') NOT NULL ,
  `Student_Address1` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL ,
  `Student_Address2` VARCHAR(22) NOT NULL ,
  `Student_Address3` VARCHAR(14) NOT NULL ,
  `Student_Phonenum` INT(10) NULL ,
  `Student_Email` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL ,
  `Student_Password` CHAR(128) NOT NULL ,
  `Enrollment_Date` DATE NOT NULL ,
  `Graduation_Date` DATE NULL ,
  `Student_Picture` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
  `PPSN` VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`StudentID`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`tblIllness` (
  `IllnessID` CHAR(5) NOT NULL ,
  `Illness_Name` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`IllnessID`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`tblStudentIllness` (
  `IllnessID` CHAR(5) NOT NULL ,
  `StudentID` INT(6) NOT NULL ,
  `Doctor_Name` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL ,
  `Doctor_Phonenum` INT(10) NOT NULL ,
  `Medication` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL ,
  `Medical_Advice` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`IllnessID`, `StudentID`) ,
  INDEX `IllnessID_idx` (`IllnessID` ASC) ,
  INDEX `StudentID_idx` (`StudentID` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `IllnessID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`IllnessID` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`tblIllness` (`IllnessID` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `StudentID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`StudentID` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`tblStudent` (`StudentID` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Answer (score 2):

[This compiles](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6cdb2) fine for me. One solution is to just remove the constraint names and they will be generated automatically for you.

```
...
CONSTRAINT 
    FOREIGN KEY (`IllnessID` )
    REFERENCES `tblIllness` (`IllnessID` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT
    FOREIGN KEY (`StudentID` )
    REFERENCES `tblStudent` (`StudentID` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.Ya it compiles for me for 3 tables, I have 26 tables though.When I compile 26 tables I still get errno: 121. When I leave out 3 of the tables it compiles fine. I am a complete novice when it comes to mySQL and this site so not sure if I should post the full code here or not. Also as the 23 tables compile ok, does that mean when you are using a 2 foreign keys as a composite primary key its ok for them to be named the same as in the table the relate to?

Comment: @Richie You can create an account at a code pasting site (pastebin) and then remove it. This will allow us to look at it and try to find the problem. I don't see a problem with the naming issue, but I would have to see the code.

Comment: Here is the code.Hope you can spot the mistakes as I can't. The seem to be in tblClassTimetable, tblContinuousAssessment, and tblContinuousAssessment. http://pastebin.com/NVZ3NF2d